Why editing PDF files is so difficult to implement?
Please redirect me in the right place if this question isn't suitable, but I'm trying to understand why editing PDF file format is such a complicated thing to implement for programmers. I am not aware of any open-source of proprietary graphical interfaces besides Adobe Acrobat that lets users edit PDF contents, by which I mean text, vector objects, forms and plethora of other objects included in the standard
Are they easy to corrupt? Are they too "bloated"? I am certain that many people have tried given the widespread adoption of the format.
I'm not aware of any other program that managed to do that and I'm trying to understand why. The closest equivalent would probably be microsoft office suite of documents, e.g. .docx, .xlsx and .ppt formats that programs like libreoffice are able to edit and save back with relative success.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. PDF is an output format.  It's not really intended for editing.  Usually you would edit the source document (in its original format), then output a new PDF when you want to give/send the file to someone else.

@BillyKerr hi,I know that pdf originates from postscript, which was indeed intended only for printing, but since then PDF became packed with so much interactivity (from forms, through javascript to multimedia) that I would be surprised to learn that somewhere in its ISO standard some editing features of text, paths etc. aren't explicitly mentioned

my theory right now by the way is partially to blame adobe for creating unnecessary complexity in order to fend the competition off and charging for their own implementations of PDFWriter and editors. I'm just wondering exactly which parts are the most difficult to implement

There are text methods in pdf @DanielKrajnik but it depends on what the purpose of the authoring software is. This isnt really a PDF editability problem but rather a general problem with vendor neutral file formats.

Your theory is partially correct. PDF is ultimately an Adobe thing, invented by them, and pushed by them and so it eventually became a standard format for publishing documents, but it was only around 2008 that they actually opened up the format as an ISO standard format for others to use.  Adobe is still very much a fan of their own creation. Other software manufacturers not so much.  Most are just quite happy to continue using it as an output/publishing format, because they already have their own editable document formats/native file formats.

@BillyKerr I dont think it is a Adobe problem per se. I think ist very much just a compatibility problem, doing something that works across all concieveble usecases is just a currenltly unsolvable problem

Inkscape, Illustrator and many other programs can open PDFs for making edits. Some programs claim they are low cost alternatives of Acrobat. Not exactly true, but I have seen there's some serious attempts done. I mean Foxit and PDF-XChange. They can even be used to insert tags to get accessible PDFs. Inkscape knows nothing of PDF tagging nor CMYK print color seoarations, but many edits are possible and Inkscape is free.
PDF format is not designed for edits. If you open a PDF generated by an advanced layout program, like Indesign you'll find that texts are splintered to numerous few letter text objects because that's how the typesetting can be professional looking as an opposite of what's available from MS Word. Placing the letters using only the data included to the font file cannot generally compete with the advanced visual balancing algorithms of pro layout programs.
Some PDF editors really try to recombine the splintered  text paragraphs to solid ones when you try to edit PDF text content. I have found that it often succeeds, but the typesetting finesses suffer. I would say that the result starts to resemble what can be got from Microsoft's programs. But that can be still useful if one makes only minor edits. To show an example of a successful case I saved this webpage from the browser as PDF and opened it in PDF-XChange Editor Plus. Turning on the text edit mode shows the guessed solid text blocks in dim grey frames. One of them (=your question) is selected-

If the PDF is not flattened nor heavily compressed, but more likely made for watching on the RGB screen you can find it's quite editable also in Inkscape. Harmfully you must remove numerous multilevel groupings and clipping masks. Inkscape has extension Deep Ungroup for that purpose. Illustrator and PDF editing programs can dissassemble the groups automatically.
Recent version of Affinity Designer also can open PDFs. It's not freeware, but well worth at least trying. It handled the easy case (=your question in GDSE) as well as PDF-XChange.
Take a compressed and flattened print PDF and try to edit it. You probably see that it's hopeless. There's the text splintering said above and all images are splintered to pieces. Some texts can be curves.  That's because the right print look is enough. There's no need to somehow make things to have their original logical relations like belonging to the same word, sentence, paragraph or image or be adjacent in the layering or reading order. To save space there's often created some impossible to guess new internal structure. Move or edit something and the whole page can start to look very different.
As said, PDFs are not designed to be editable, they are designed to present the visual (and also the interactive form) appearance of a document as is and do it effectively.
Not asked, but practical PDF editing is sometimes needed, because the customer gets the layout from the layout artist as PDF if he hasn't paid a substantial extra for getting it as an easy to edit Illustrator or Indesign file. The customer wants to save money and that clashes with artist's intentions. Giving a flattened and compressed PDF is a good way for the artist to smile friendly and sound generous by saying "You purchased it, it's yours, make edits as you like".

Thank you, I might have underestimated complexity of handling fonts/typesetting and various "flattening" optimizations - that sounds like more convincing arguments than just "feature creep" or vague standards.

Could you let me know what you meant by "some impossible to guess new internal structure"? PDF is still an ISO standard, right? Programs shouldn't be able to introduce anything that wouldn't be readable?

@DanielKrajnik they arent introducing anyrhing that isnt readable. But they are making editing hard by keeping the same look as in original file format because they split and convert things to less easily editable primitives. There is nothing you can do about that.

@DanielKrajnik The "Impossible to guess" may be well defined in the specifications  (and hopefully not trashed by software bugs), but ordinary end users, like me cannot intuitively understand such complexity and the behaviour of the PDF under edit attempts  looks unpredictable.

TL;DR
Any nonnative format is going to sacrafice some editability. Native formats sacrafice inteoperability.

This isnt so much about PDF as to why exporting things between software might not work out. Similar things happen with SVG, STEP, DXF, STL etc.
So PDF is entirely editable, no problem with that. However, you might not find it practical to edit the PDF file. This is entirely another thing.
This is often caused by the property of the export chain. Nothing actually forces software developpers to export a very editable file. There are many reasons for this from expediency to retaining of look and feel.
So imagine that you are a software vendor and your software works with nonuniform rational b-splines (because that makes it expedient for you to work in projective spaces). Now PDF works on bezier splines. Client needs to get a PDF file for printing. Well the easiest way for you to get out of this is to flatten your curves to straight segments.
Is this editable? Well, yes but not originally editable, and not very practical. Admittedly its not the best export we could do. We could fit beziers on the NURB Spline. But this is also not necceserily nice for end user editability. So options are bad, lot of work and bad.
Lets take another example. You are exporting a table and graphs from a spreadsheet. Now you can export everything as is in your engine. Only problem, changing the table values does not reflect in the graph, so not editable to the end user easily.
And a final example. You have a text layout engine that takes care of making each page look as even as possible. And then you dump that into a PDF file. Well youd like the user to be able to print it as you intended. But now editability suffers because the editor does not have your layout engine to reflow the entire document. Not really editable.
So you see editability is somewhat impossible in a environment that does not stop end user applications developpers to add features to their software.
Even if forced all developpers conform to a editability standard, you cant stop the user from doing this on purpose for some reason.
PS: PDF, SVG and STEP also suffer from sheer size of stuff in the standard. This makes it hard to even just draw things properly, let alone let user edit the primitives.

Because PDFs are in essence a file container format NOT to be edited.
The priority is to maintain consistency in format. It is an output format.
Depending on the version some elements do not even exist anymore. A text with a shadow could be flattened as a raster image.
Paragraphs are broken in small chunks to maintain the visual separation of the characters and words.
Some texts are not text anymore, they could be just vectors in the shape of a text.
A spreadsheet will lose every formula and only have the final data.

The process is, that you have an editable file. A Word document, an Illustrator, or InDesign file. Then you export it to PDF so it is fixed. People will see the final result, the final shapes, the final data on the table.
If you need changes, you go back to the source file and export a new version.
There are a few exceptions. You can send a Logo with text converted to curves because it is not text anymore, but part of the logo.
This PDF file can be used as a master to extract the logo in different applications, edit it, change the color, and then export a new PDF file.

Editing PDF files can be challenging due to their complex structure, which includes text, images, and formatting information, often requiring specialized software and handling.
